# Input string was not in a correct format (c#)

Tags: c#

After running the page on a browser, i get the: Input string was not in a correct format.

```
List<int> TheGroupIds = new List<int>();
if (Request.QueryString["MultiAssignInteractionGrouIds"] != null 
    && Request.QueryString["MultiAssignInteractionGrouIds"] != "" 
    && Request.QueryString["MultiAssignInteractionGrouIds"] != "-2")
{
    string GroupIds = Request.QueryString["MultiAssignInteractionGrouIds"];
    TheGroupIds = GroupIds.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList(); <= 'The error is HERE' 
    TheGroupIds = TheGroupIds.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Comment: can you post the data source of that?

Comment: One of the "split" GroupIds is not a valid integer value, or is null.

Comment: and what is Request.QueryString["MultiAssignInteractionGrouIds"]; ?

Comment: Use the debugger. You could pprevent the error with `int.TryParse` but maybe that hides just the real bug. Why do you have invalid integers?

Comment: Basically one of the values after you split on comma is not an integer.  If you need to deal with that you should use `int.TryParse` instead, and then it would be better to use a loop instead of Linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the debugger knows, but maybe you have values like `"1,2,,3,4"`, then use this `Split`:

```
string groupIds = Request.QueryString["MultiAssignInteractionGrouIds"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupIds) &&  groupIds != "-2")
{
    TheGroupIds = groupIds.Split(new[]{ ','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
     .Select(int.Parse)
     .Distinct()
     .ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: `int.Parse` will work even if there is [leading or trailing whitespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2).

Answer (score 0):

String contains not only intgeres. You can filter you text or use this converter:

```
public static int? ToNullableInt(this string s)
{
    int i;
    if (int.TryParse(s, out i)) return i;
    return null;
}
```

And the filter nullable values. Usages:

```
var result = text.Split(';').Select(x => x.ToNullableInt()).Where(y => y != null).ToList();
```